# Shell scripting if-else loop

Tags: linux, shell, variables

```
#!/bin/sh

$status=""lifecycle-state": "STOPPED""
$LifecycleStatus =$(**command1** to list status | grep Stopped)

echo $lifecyleStatus  
echo $status

if [ $LifecycleStatus == $status]
then
   echo "******* Current date: $(date) "
    **Command2** to start instance    
else    
    echo "Instance is already in stopped state"    
fi
```

I get the error as

```
line 3: =: command not found
line 4: =: command not found
```

Learning scripting, can anyone please help me why this isnt take the variables in to it.

So my command1 will result something like ""lifecycle-state": "STOPPED"" but when I echo it isnt taking variables to compare to use in if else loop.

Comment: Run your script through [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net/). You have several syntax errors.

Comment: Your nested quotes are a show stopper.

Comment: using `#!/bin/sh` is ambiguous, as in the unix enviroment it refers to the (original) Bourne Shell, while in Linix it can also be `ash`, `dash` and maybe a few others (NOT `bash` or `ksh`!) . The Original Bourne Shell doesn't support `$(cmd-stubstitution)` and you have to use back-quotes instead. Not sure about `dash`. If at all possible use `#!/bin/bash` instead. Even that will have version differences that you'll have to manage (rare and obscure, to be sure). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Like any shebang, its interpretation is system-specific. `#!/bin/sh` is perfectly fine if that's the path to the local system's POSIX-compliant shell (and your script is intended to be run by a POSIX-compliant shell). It is not at all uncommon for `/bin/sh` to be a link to or copy of `bash`.

Comment: Thank you guys. Since my grep command1 gives the result as lifecycle-state": "STOPPED string. Only string which I need to check is "Stopped" option. Is there a way to just send that part of my command1 result (after :) in to the variable

Comment: Sorry, that is unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Please update your Q with exact sample output of your `ps...` cmd, and then show your required output from that sample. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-select text to have the correct formatting for `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.